# Share Laravel Models in multiple apps?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, bitbucket

I have two applications in Laravel and they have the same exact models.
In order to have the models in one single place, to maintain them easier I made a Bitbucket private repository with the following structure:

```
database-models
-src
--Models
---Database
----Post.php
composer.json
```

The composer.json file is like this:

```
{
  "name":"database-models",
  "autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
      "DbModels\\":"src/"
    }
  }
}
```

This is actually the first time that I do the private repo and all this setup so in order to test my private repo code I pulled in on of the applications the code via composer repositories:

```
"require": {
...
"user/database-models":"*"
},
"repositories": [
        {
            "type":"package",
            "package": {
                "name": "user/database-models",
                "version":"master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "git@bitbucket.org:user/database-models.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference":"master"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

By me so far is ok and the next and the most important step I am creating a Command in the app that is something like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DbModels\Models\Database\Post;

...

public function handle()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    dd($posts);
}
```

I am running `composer dump-autoload` after the install of this package but when I run the command the error that i get is:

```
Class 'DbModels\Models\Database\Post' not found
```

I have the feeling that this error is pretty obvious but I can't get my finger on it. Can someone give me a hint or a solution to this issue? What am I doing wrong here?

**LATER EDIT**:

The Post.php file is like this:

```
<?php namespace DbModels\Models\Database;

// Used namespaces.
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class Post.
 *
 * @package App\Models\Database
 */
class Post extends Model
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two separate apps using the same models? Can they not be merged into the same codebase if it’s say, a front-end web application and an API?

Comment: i'd check that the namespace are correct i.e your Post.php file has namespace DbModels\Models\Database;

Comment: The two apps I think is not the scope of the question. Sure this may be something weird for some.

Comment: Does your package show up when running: `composer show -i`

Comment: in your model package your user namespace is missing, should be `"name":"user/database-models"`

Comment: @zyglobe - yes, the package is there